# How do I fix a nil value error produced when calling in a widget method in Corona SDK?

Tags: lua, coronasdk

How do I fix a nil value error produced when calling in a widget method in Corona SDK?

```
 local widget = require('widget')

-- Text Box
 local myTextField = widget.newTextField(
{     
     top = 10,
     left = 20,
     width = 200,
     height = 30,
     cornerRadius = 8,
     strokeWidth = 3,
     backgroundColor = {1,1,1},
     strokeColor = {0,0,0},
     font = 'Helvetica',
     fontsize = 24,
     listener = textFieldHandler    
}
)
```

Comment: How is anyone supposed to help if you do not even post the error message...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the documentation widget only provides the following function:

https://docs.coronalabs.com/api/library/widget/

```
widget.newButton()
widget.newPickerWheel()
widget.newProgressView()
widget.newScrollView()
widget.newSegmentedControl()
widget.newSlider()
widget.newSpinner()
widget.newStepper()
widget.newSwitch()
widget.newTabBar()
widget.newTableView()
widget.setTheme()
```

You can avoid the error message, which I assume is something like Error: Attempt to calla nil value, by simply not calling the nil value `widget.newTextField`.

Another option is to implement it yourself as described here in detail:

https://coronalabs.com/blog/2013/12/03/tutorial-customizing-text-input/

As this tutorial exactly matches your code I assume you were just to lazy to read beyond the first paragraph...

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I probably should have deleted this question because,  right after I posted it, I realized that it is a function that I had to manually write.